# Obtener el value del radio button seleccionado en Angular 6 utilizando Reactive Forms

Tags: angular

Estoy usando **Angular 6.2.7** y tengo un formulario con **Reactive Form** en el cual tengo un radio group con dos radio button.

**HTML:**

```
<form
      [formGroup]="signUpForm"
      (ngSubmit)="onSubmit()">

        <div class="radio">
          <div *ngFor="let gender of genderValues">
            <label>
              <input
                formControlName="gender"
                value="{{gender}}"
                type="radio"
                name="gender"
                (change)="radioChangeHandler($event)">
              {{gender === 'Male' ? 'Hombre' : 'Mujer'}}
            </label>
          </div>
        </div>
</form>
```

**TS:**

```
signUpForm: FormGroup;
genderValues = ['Male', ' Female'];

constructor(private formBuilder: FormBuilder) {
}

this.signUpForm = this.formBuilder.group({
      // Asigno un gender como default
      gender: [this.genderValues[0], [
        Validators.required
      ]]
    });

radioChangeHandler(event: any) {
    // Guardar value nuevo
    this.gender.setValue(event.target.value);
    console.log(this.gender.value);
  }

get gender() {
    return this.signUpForm.get('gender');
}
```

El `radioChangeHandler` no funciona. Cuando seleccionas uno de los dos radio button el valor no cambia y no se guarda. He intentado varias formas que he encontrado en Internet y no he tenido éxito.

Gracias de antemano.

Answer (score 1):

Pienso que en vez de enviar el evento pueder enviar el género

```
(change)="radioChangeHandler(gender)"

radioChangeHandler(gender: string) {
  this.gender.setValue(gender);
  console.log(this.gender.value);
}
```

Comment: Así es, el evento solo envía `true` o `false` para el radiobutton seleccionado y deseleccionado, respectivamente.

Comment: No me funciona. Al hacer clic en los radio button no se imprime nada en consola. Es como si el `(change)` no funcionara y por ende no envía nada a la función `radioChangeHandler`. Alguna idea?